# Probability question related to discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

***Problem:***
Three cards are drawn randomly (without replacement) from a standard deck of playing cards.

a. Let the random variable *X* be the number of face cards in the three cards drawn. Show your calculations for finding its expected value *E*[*X*].

b. Suppose each Jack is worth 1 point, and each Queen or King 2 points, while all other cards are worth zero points. Let the random variable *Y* be the sum of the points in the three cards drawn. Find the expected value *E*[*Y*].

c. Show your calculation of Var(*X*) and Var(*Y*) for the random variables described in part (a) and part (b).

d. Find the probability distribution function of *Y*.

---

This is what I know:

a) The equation used is discrete random variable:
$$E[X]= \displaystyle\sum_{x} x \cdot P(x)$$

I know that for each of the face cards (Jack, Queen and King) there is a $$\frac{4}{52}$$ probability at one suit. How do I show the complete calculation based on what I know?

b) This question is slightly different from part (a) and changes everything by giving a value to the face cards. So how does this change the probability and the calculation for the discrete random variable for *Y*?

c) Once I know this I should try to find the variance of *X* and *Y* with the following equation:
$$Var(X)=E[(x-E[X])^2]$$
$$Var(Y)=E[(y-E[Y]^2]$$

d) Now the problem asks me to know for the probability distribution of *Y*? I assume that I should try to see if the values of *Y* are close to E[*Y*] or scattered far from E[*Y*].

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the probabilities change each time you draw a card! So in fact, your denominator will decrease by one for each card you draw. For part a, I suggest doing a table for finding the expected value. Finding the variance should be the next part but to calculate $E[X^2$] and $E[Y^2$], just square the values you obtain from the table but not the probabilities since those are "fixed". I approached a similar problem last semester on my probability class but except it was about rolling a die and not cards.